# How can i use the functions of "survey" package in "expss" package in R

Tags: survey, weighted, expss

I try to use the `expss` packages for survey data analysis, but the result of standard errors, variances and confidence intervals differ of the `survey` package result.

In `survey`:

```
dclus1<-svydesign(id=~dnum, weights=~pw, data=apiclus1, fpc=~fpc)
svyby(~api99, ~stype, dclus1, svymean)

  stype    api99       se
E     E 607.7917 22.81660
H     H 595.7143 41.76400
M     M 608.6000 32.56064
```

In `expss`:

```
apiclus1 %>% tab_cells(api99) %>% 
         tab_rows(stype) %>% tab_weight(pw) %>%
         tab_stat_fun(w_mean,w_se) %>% tab_pivot()

 |       |    |       |        | #Total |
 | ----- | -- | ----- | ------ | ------ |
 | stype |  E | api99 |   mean |  607.8 |
 |       |    |       |     se |    1.6 |
 |       |  H | api99 |   mean |  595.7 |
 |       |    |       |     se |    4.7 |
 |       |  M | api99 |   mean |  608.6 |
 |       |    |       |     se |    3.7 |
```

How can i use the functions of `survey` package within `expss`?

Comment: maybe use the `srvyr` package?

Comment: Could you provide example of your data for reproducability?